# It should continue to accept a price of an item and displays the current total while the user input is not equals to zero

Tags: loops, arraylist, while-loop

/* I need some help. I'm stuck with this code. It should continue to accept a price of an item and displays the current total while the user input is not equal to zero. However, output for the current total won't show the current amount. */

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String customerName;
    char promtSenior;
    int num = 1;
    double itemPrice;
    double currentTotal = 0;
    ArrayList<Double> amounts = new ArrayList<Double>();
    System.out.print("Please enter customer name: ");
    customerName = scanner.nextLine();

    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Please enter item " + num++ + " price or 0 to quit: ");
        itemPrice = scanner.nextDouble();
        amounts.add(itemPrice);
        scanner.nextLine();
        for (double i : amounts) {
                currentTotal = currentTotal + i ;  
            }
            System.out.println(currentTotal);
    

        if (itemPrice == 0) {
            System.out.println("Are you a Senior Citizen? [Y/N]: " + customerName);
            promtSenior = scanner.next().charAt(0);
            if (promtSenior == 'N') {
                System.out.println("No Discount");
            }
        }
    }         
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```cs
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Please enter item " + num++ + " price or 0 to quit: ");
    itemPrice = scanner.nextDouble();
    amounts.add(itemPrice);
    scanner.nextLine();
    for (double i : amounts) {
            currentTotal = currentTotal + i ;  
            System.out.println(currentTotal); 
    }
```

should be this as previously you where printing the total after the for loop not during
i think you accidentally messed up your curly brackets and indented before